# How to make subsection text smaller and retain numbering functionality?

Tags: fonts, bold, subsection, custom

I use this package for making the subsection text smaller:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
```

However, for some reason, the numbering gets lost, when I use this line of code to control the subsection:

```
\titleformat{\subsection}{\normalfont\fontsize{8pt}{12pt}\selectfont\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
```

What I wanted is to still retain the common functionality of `\subsection`: **4.4** for example. But instead, all the `\subsection` command does for me with the modification is this:

**4** Test

**4** Test

Here a minimal reproducible example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec} 
\titleformat{\subsection}{\normalfont\fontsize{8pt}{12pt}\selectfont\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\title{TEST}
\author{TEST}

\begin{document}
    
\maketitle
    
\newpage
\section{TEST}
\subsection{OTHER TEST}
\subsection{YET ANOTHER TEST}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Welcomed to TeX.SE! Have you tried to write `{Subsection \thesection}` in your command?

Comment: @Jes What do you mean exactly?

Comment: Nevermind,  @Mico already answered!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `\thesection` to `\thesubsection` in the third-to-last argument of `\titleformat`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec} 
\titleformat{\subsection}{\normalfont\fontsize{8pt}%
   {12pt}\selectfont\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}

\begin{document}

\section{TEST}
\subsection{OTHER TEST}
\subsection{YET ANOTHER TEST}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the warm welcome and the nice answer. :)

Comment: @MySQLInjection - Many thanks for the accept. This may be a new speed record, for me at least, in receiving an accept after posting an answer. :-)